# SQL Grouped Rows show only distinct values when they dont match other rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to build a SQL query for MS Access to show data for specific groups, that only shows rows when a secondary column has unique values. For this data:

```
|ID  | Crate | Fruit |
----------------------
|1   | C1   | Apple |
|2   | C1   | Apple |
|3   | C2   | Apple |
|4   | C2   | Banana|
|5   | C2   | Pear  |
|6   | C3   | Banana|
|7   | C3   | Banana|
|8   | C4   | Apple |
|9   | C4  | Pear   |
```

I would like it to display

```
|ID  | Crate | Fruit |
----------------------
|3   | C2   | Apple |
|4   | C2   | Banana|
|5   | C2   | Pear  |
|8   | C4   | Apple |
|9   | C4   | Pear  |
```

Struggling on this because I know I can count values that meet certain criteria, but not how to do that when then criteria is just "not the same as the rest of your group".

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```sql
Select 
    ID, 
    Crate, 
    Fruit
From 
    Crates
Where 
    (Select Min(T.Fruit) <> Max(T.Fruit) 
    From Crates As T 
    Where T.Crate = Crates.Crate) = True
```